# Access an instance variable without using the @ sign

Tags: ruby

Here is an example from a book:

```
class TextCompressor
  attr_reader :unique, :index
  def initialize( text )
    @unique = []
    @index = []
    add_text( text )
  end
  def add_text( text )
    words = text.split
    words.each { |word| add_word( word ) }
  end
  def add_word( word )
    i = unique_index_of( word ) || add_unique_word( word )
    @index << i
  end
  def unique_index_of( word )
    @unique.index(word)
  end
  def add_unique_word( word )
    @unique << word
    unique.size - 1
  end
end
```

In the method `add_unique_word` the author access the variable `unique` without using the @ sign (`unique.size - 1`). How is it possible, and why it is so?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This line `attr_reader :unique, :index` created a `getter` for the attribute:

```
def unique
 @unique
end
```

what you see in the line `unique.size - 1` is a method call to the getter, then accesing the `size` property of it.

Answer (score 8):

The `attr_reader :unique` call adds an accessor making `@unique` publicly available at `unique`. It's a strange choice that the author made to mix and match using both `@unique` and `unique` though.